# Application logging with log4j 1 or log4j 2 and Tomcat 9 not working

Tags: tomcat, log4j, log4j2, tomcat9

I am migrating an existing web application from Tomcat 8.5 to Tomcat 9.

The webapp uses Log4j 1 with Commons-Logging. While everything used to work fine in Tomcat 8.5 I don't get *any log output in Tomcat 9*.
Trying to get to the bottom of this, I created a simple test-servlet and also tried to migrate from Log4J1 to Log4J2. The effect is the same.
I have found a [similar post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865690/how-to-configure-application-logging-using-log4j-on-tomcat-9) but the author stated at the end that the troubles originated from some SLF4J-dependencies, which does not count for my case. I am just using Log4J.

This is the **pom.xml** I am using

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>webtest2</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>webtest2 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!--  Log4J 1.2 + commons-logging
            https://o7planning.org/de/10151/anleitung-java-commons-logging 
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.17</version>
       </dependency>  
     -->
    
    <!--   Log4J 2 + commons-logging
            https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/java-logging/jcl-log4j2.html  -->
            
        <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
           <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>           
            
            
     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>        
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>webtest2</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Testcase 1: For Log4J1**, following the [tutorial for Log4J1](https://o7planning.org/de/10151/anleitung-java-commons-logging)
I am using the following **commons-logging.properties**

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

and the following **log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA
 
#Console Appender
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

**Testcase 2: For Log4J2**, following the [tutorial 1 for Log4J2](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/java-logging/jcl-log4j2.html)
I am using the following **log4j2.properties**  (the commons-logging.properties does not seem to be needed)

```
appenders=xyz

appender.xyz.type = Console
appender.xyz.name = myOutput
appender.xyz.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.xyz.layout.pattern = %d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p %c{1} [%L] - %m%n

rootLogger.level = info

rootLogger.appenderRefs = abc

rootLogger.appenderRef.abc.ref = myOutput
```

**Testcase 3: For Log4J2**, alternatively I tried to use the **log4j2.xml** following the [reference for Log4J2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

```xml
<!--  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html -->
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
      <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
      </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
      <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      </Root>
    </Loggers>
  </Configuration>
```

All the simple test cases I stated, work fine with Tomcat 8.5. With Tomcat 9 I don't get any output. Specifically I am using Tomcat Version / JVM Version

Apache Tomcat/8.5.39 (Ubuntu)   11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04

Apache Tomcat/9.0.16 (Ubuntu)   11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04

Just as the author of the question I stated above, I am wondering if this has to do with some conflicts with the internal logging in Tomcat 9. But the logging-documentation explicitely states that any web app may come with its own logging.
Right now, I am just lost and appreciate any help.

**Thanx!!**

PS:

In case you are interested, this is the servlet-code

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Testservlet
 */
public class Testservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Testservlet.class);

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public Testservlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Starting doGet ...");
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Starting doPost ...");
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

And this is the web.xml code

```xml
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Testservlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Testservlet</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>mygroup.Testservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Testservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Testservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```